# How to display the music that is playing on my app in blackberry messenger status?

Tags: android-studio, blackberry, audio-player

I want to show the song that is playing in my application appear on the status of blackberry messenger, how to play the song that is playing to appear on the status of blackberry mesengger ??
Thanks before..

Comment: Refer to the [Blackberry documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/key_classes_1489647_11.html)

Comment: Thanks for answere, can u give me a sample code for this?